# How to use a variable to specify line to be replaced by sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I want to replace a specific line in a text file based on a variable. So if my variable happened to be 4, I couldn't just write:

```
sed -i '4 creplacememt' text.txt
```

I want to know how to do something like this:

```
num=4
str="$num creplacement" 
sed -i $str text.txt
```

which gives me an error. What exactly am I doing wrong / how could I accomplish this?

Comment: Quotes. `sed -i -e "$str" text.txt`

Comment: Double quotes can save you some troubles. If the variable can contain sed special characters, they're not enough.

Comment: Set your [variable into quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/222967). 

    sed -i -e "$str" text.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash -e

# Replace given the line number with the given string in the given file

line=$1
str=$2
shift 2

sed -i "$line{s/.*/$str/}" "$@"
```

Usage:

```
script [line-number] [string] [file]

# Eg:
script 4 foobar my-file
script 3,9 'lines three to nine of "my-file" now contain this very string' my-file
```

You'll have to escape slashes in the replacement string.

You can also use regexes (`/regex.*/`) instead of line numbers.